# Convert data from a simple JSON format to a DSV format

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file in Unix, with data sample like the following:

```
{"ID":"123", "Region":"Asia", "Location":"India"}
{"ID":"234", "Region":"APAC", "Location":"Australia"}
{"ID":"345", "Region":"Americas", "Location":"Mexio"}
{"ID":"456", "Region":"Americas", "Location":"Canada"}
{"ID":"567", "Region":"APAC", "Location":"Japan"}
```

The desired output is

```
ID|Region|Location
123|Asia|India
234|APAC|Australia
345|Americas|Mexico
456|Americas|Canada
567|APAC|Japan
```

I tried with a few sed commands. I could remove the following: '{', '}', ' " ', ':'

There are 2 issues with the output file

1. All rows from input appear in single line in the output.
2. Adding the pipe ('|') as delimiter.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: So, you want to convert JSON format into CSV (DSV) format. Do you have any oddball data to worry about (ID or region or location values containing `|`, for example)? Do you have any irregularities in the input (like a line suddenly containing extra fields, or missing a field, or containing the fields in a different order)? Do you need to deal with other sets of input data with different column names? You've got some answers that deal with data files that are beautifully regular and consistent with what is shown in the question — and they may be perfectly adequate for your task.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Yes, I am looking for conversion of JSON data into tabular data. This is standard format of data and will not spring surprises. There are no surprises expected in input data as well. The column set will not change.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the tool `jq` (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/); `jq` is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

```
jq -r '"\(.ID)|\(.Region)|\(.Location)"' < infile

123|Asia|India
234|APAC|Australia
345|Americas|Mexio
456|Americas|Canada
567|APAC|Japan
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` is `--raw-output`

Comment: For proper tool, +1. But I dunno the use of `( )`

Comment: Is there a way to get the heading output too?

Comment: try to use the `keys` function in jq, but the results are not very satisfactory: `jq -r '"\(keys[0])|\(keys[1])|\(keys[2])","\(.ID)|\(.Region)\(.Location)"'  infile`

Answer (score 1):

Through awk,

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS="|" 'BEGIN{print "ID|Region|Location"}{print $4,$8,$12}' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
{"ID":"123", "Region":"Asia", "Location":"India"}
{"ID":"234", "Region":"APAC", "Location":"Australia"}
{"ID":"345", "Region":"Americas", "Location":"Mexio"}
{"ID":"456", "Region":"Americas", "Location":"Canada"}
{"ID":"567", "Region":"APAC", "Location":"Japan"}
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS="|" 'BEGIN{print "ID|Region|Location"}{print $4,$8,$12}' file
ID|Region|Location
123|Asia|India
234|APAC|Australia
345|Americas|Mexio
456|Americas|Canada
567|APAC|Japan
```

**EXplanation:**

- `-F'"'` Sets `"` as Field Separator value.
- `OFS="|"` Sets `|` as Output Field Separator value.
- Atfirst, awk would execute the function inside the BEGIN block. It helps to print the header section.

Answer (score 1):

This sed one-liner does what you want. It's capturing the field values using parenthesized expressions, and then putting them into the output using \1, \2, and \3.

```
s/^{"ID":"\([^"]*\)", "Region":"\([^"]*\)", "Location":"\([^"]*\)"}$/\1|\2|\3/
```

Invoke it like:

```
$ sed -f one-liner.sed input.txt
```

Or you can invoke it within a Bash script, producing the header:

```
echo 'ID|Region|Location'
sed -e 's/^{"ID":"\([^"]*\)", "Region":"\([^"]*\)", "Location":"\([^"]*\)"}$/\1|\2|\3/' $input
```

Comment: Except for the column headings line required in the output, which requires the one-liner to become a three-liner but is otherwise easily done.

Answer (score 0):

It is a JSON file so it is best to use a JSON parser. Here is a perl implementation of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

open my $fh, '<', 'path/to/your/file';

#keys of your structure
my @key = qw(ID Region Location);

print join ("|", @key), "\n";

#iterate over your file, decode it and print in order of your key structure
while (my $json = <$fh>) {
    my $text = decode_json($json); 
    print join ("|", map { $$text{$_} } @key ),"\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
ID|Region|Location
123|Asia|India
234|APAC|Australia
345|Americas|Mexio
456|Americas|Canada
567|APAC|Japan
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using sed as follows**

Command line

```
echo "my_string" |
sed -e 's#[,:"{}]##g' -e 's#ID##g' -e "s#Region##g"  -e 's#Location##g' \
    -e '1 s#^.*$#ID Region Location\n&#'  -e 's# #|#g'
```

or

```
sed -e 's#[,:"{}]##g' -e 's#ID##g' -e "s#Region##g" -e 's#Location##g' \
    -e '1 s#^.*$#ID Region Location\n&#'  -e 's# #|#g' my_file
```

I tried this in a terminal as follows:

```
echo '{"ID":"123", "Region":"Asia", "Location":"India"}
{"ID":"234", "Region":"APAC", "Location":"Australia"}
{"ID":"345", "Region":"Americas", "Location":"Mexio"}
{"ID":"456", "Region":"Americas", "Location":"Canada"}
{"ID":"567", "Region":"APAC", "Location":"Japan"}' |
sed -e 's#[,:"{}]##g' -e 's#ID##g' -e "s#Region##g" -e 's#Location##g' \
    -e '1 s#^.*$#ID Region Location\n&#'  -e 's# #|#g'
```

Output

```
ID|Region|Location
123|Asia|India
234|APAC|Australia
345|Americas|Mexio
456|Americas|Canada
567|APAC|Japan
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, this works fine with GNU `sed`; BSD `sed` doesn't interpolate the newline properly.  An alternative approach to inserting the header line is to use the `i` (insert) command, which has to be followed in standard `sed` by backslash, newline, and the header line as part of the same `-e` argument.  Also note that this approach will insert pipes between the words of 'El Salvador' etc.  It is possible to avoid doing that, but it requires a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your response and the pointers/ solutions did help a lot. 
For some mysterious reasons, I couldn't get any sed commands work. So, I devised my own solution. Although it's not elegant, it's still worked.
Here is the script I prepared which resolved the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ource file path.
infile=/home/exfile.txt

# remove if these temp file exist already.
rm ./efile.txt ./xfile.txt ./yfile.txt ./zfile.txt

# removing the curly braces from input file.
cat exfile.txt | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1 >> ./efile.txt

# setting input file name to different value.
infile=./efile.txt

# remove double quotes from the file.
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line | sed 's/\"//g' >> ./xfile.txt

done < "$infile"

# creating another temp file.
infile2=./xfile.txt


# remove colon from file.
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line | sed 's/\:/,/g' >> ./yfile.txt
done < "$infile2"

# set input file path to new temp file.
infile3=yfile.txt

# initialize variables to hold header column values.
t1=0
t3=0
t5=0


# read each of the line to extract header row. Exit loop after reading 1st row.
once=1
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 
do
    "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6"
    t1=$f1
    t3=$f3
    t5=$f5

    if [ "$once" -eq 1 ]; then
        break
    fi
 done < "$infile3"

# Read each of the line from input file. Write only the value to another output file.
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6
do
    echo "$f2|$f4|$f6" >> ./zfile.txt

done < "$infile3"

# insert the header column row into the file generated in the step above.
frstline="$t1|$t3|$t5"
sed -i '1i ID|Region|Location' ./zfile.txt
```